# How do I add or subtract String values to an object, and set the value to "none" when it's empty?

Tags: java

I have a class `Passengers` which has member properties `String name`, `int health`, and `String disease` with setter and getter methods. The `disease` variable will initially hold `null`. Here's that class

```
public class Passengers
{
    private String name;
    private int health;
    private String disease;

    public Passengers(String _name, int _health, String _disease)
    {
        name = _name;
        health = _health;
        disease = _disease;
    }

    public void setHealth(int _health)
    {
        health = _health;
    }
    public void setDisease(String _disease)
    {
        disease = _disease;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public int getHealth()
    {
        return health;
    }
    public String getDisease()
    {
        return disease;
    }
}
```

What I want to know is how I could add new strings onto this variable, and then how to take away. For example, a passenger Bill starts at `null` for his diseases, and then contracts malaria and the cold. Bill's `disease` variable should now hold `malaria, cold`. Now say the user chooses to treat Bill's malaria. How would I 
1) add malaria and cold
2) subtract just malaria from `disease`?

Whenever I attempt to change the disease with

```
passengers[index].setDisease() = null;
```

it says "error: method setDisease in class Passengers cannot be applied to given types:
required: String
found: no arguments"

Comment: look up arraylist, or Set if you dont want to allow duplicates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should give the class a `List<String>` such as an `ArrayList<String>` and put the diseases in this List.

Better still, create a class or enum of Disease and have your Passenger class use a `List<Disease>` and avoid over-use of String. You could then give the class public `addDisease(Disease disease)` and `removeDisease(Disease disease)` methods.

Incidentally, your class above should be named Passenger, the singular, not Passengers, the plural, since it represents the concept of a single Passenger.

Comment: I will give that a try, thanks for the suggestion. Additionally, if I make a disease class, I'll be able to program in behaviors for the disease as well, like KILL THE PASSENGER!! after x days c:

Comment: @TonyWhite: yes that's correct. As an aside, you might want to adjust the dose of your medications.

Comment: Also note that Jean's suggestion to use a Set is a very good one (1+ to him), and you would do well to follow it.

Comment: Shall I use Set instead of creating a Disease class? Like, does the Set go inside of the Passenger class?

Comment: @TonyWhite: they are not mutually exclusive. You should create a Disease class and then have Passenger hold a `Set<Disease>`, likely it will be a concrete `HashSet<Disease>`.

Comment: Will do, on a slightly related note, if a user has a disease for x amount of days and "dies", is it possible to set a `final` value of 0 with `setHealth`? Meaning that, no matter the amount of medication they use, it will never increase the health, and they therefore lose the benefits of that surviving character

Comment: @TonyWhite: what do you mean by "final" value? I imagine that your different Disease objects would reduce the victim's health at different rates. When health runs out, the victim dies.

Comment: What I meant was, yeah a disease will decrease the health at a given rate, but I also have an Item `medicine` that players can use to cure diseases and increase health. I want to make it to where, if health reaches 0, the medicine will no longer increase the health. I called it `final` because I recall from my java class that a `final` variable cannot be changed by public methods. Come to think of it, though, I guess I could just use an if statement for the medicine-related methods that prevents its use if `health = 0`

Comment: You couldn't use the Java `final` keyword for that, but you could have code in the setter for health that would check if the health was 0, and not allow the modification. Or you could have a separate `alive` boolean field, and once the patient was dead (`!alive`), not allow further modifications.

Comment: @TonyWhite: final variables should not be changed ever. So if you make health final, it cannot be changed at all during the program run. No, this will not help you, and you should use final for class constants, and for fields and parameters that don't change. You will need to use logic to prevent a health of <= 0 from increasing. The `setHealth(...)` method could control this.

Answer (score 3):

I would reccomend making disease a [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) of Strings.

```
Set<String> diseases = new HashSet<String>();

void addDisease(String disease) {
    diseases.add(disease);
}

void removeDisease(String deisease) {
    diseases.remove(disease);
}
```

`Set`s are "better", in this case, than other `Collections` because they cannot hold duplicates.

Comment: Sets can't hold duplicates, and Lists can. I think you said the opposite of what you meant, in your last statement.

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement if you are using `List` like `ArrayList` you can access your elements(disease names) by `index`, but it will allow duplicate data to be inserted(same disease may be added multiple times, it will unnecessary increase in number of diseases and may arise some problems).
If you use `Set` like `HashSet` it will allow unique element only, so no issues related to duplicated entries but at the same time you can't access a `particular disease by index` (if you need so, as of now I am not aware of your further requirement).
So as best of my knowledge I suggest you to use `LinkedHashSet(HashSet with Linked approach)` it will provide you FIFO order without duplicate insertion problem.